# Is there any way to WCF Service be aware of which SharePoint user is using Cilckonce application?

Tags: wpf, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, clickonce

I have WPF Clickonce application deployed online as SharePoint Solution Package. I have logged SharePoint user (Active Directory Authentication) and on server I have WCF Service. On a SharePoint site I click link to open the ClickOnce application, from opened application I send an request to server via WCF Service. Is there any way to make WCF Service aware of which SharePoint user send this request (request from Clickonce App)?

Comment: If it is using AD authentication, could you not just supply System.Environment.Username as a parameter passed from your ClickOnce to the WCF service method call? Or are you trying to impersonate the security of the logged in user?

Comment: This clickonce app was originally a silverlight app. The problem is in silverlight application everything was done using default credentials and the WCF Services took care of which person did the action. I wonder if I can do the same thing in clickonce app without passing user to clickonce application.